# Android Google Drive - folder change listener

Tags: android, listener, google-drive-android-api

I noticed that in new Google Drive API (v2) & Google Play Services (04.03.23) there is [change listeners to receive notifications whenever a specified file or folder has changes to its contents or metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events). How to use it as listener for listening changes in whole appdata folder (folder used for application data only)? Thank you for any help in advance.

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, mSelectedFileId);
file.addChangeListener(mGoogleApiClient, changeListener);

DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, mSelectedFileId);
file.removeChangeListener(mGoogleApiClient, changeListener);

final private Listener<ChangeEvent> changeListener = new Listener<ChangeEvent>() 
 {
 @Override
 public void onEvent(ChangeEvent event) 
     {
     mLogTextView.setText(String.format("File change event: %s", event));
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.await()` or `.setResultCallback()` on the `.addChangeListener` and `.removeChangeListener` calls for them to be activated. This is not included on the Drive website; Ive written a [post](https://plus.google.com/+ZoltanDemant/posts/2sKyve4cwsU) to them about it.

You can check the returned status of the call afterwards to make sure that it has been properly set (setting a listener on the app folder doesnt seem to be working, at least in my case).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient,Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(googleApiClient).getDriveId());
folder.addChangeListener(mGoogleApiClient, changeListener);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is only my problem, but it take a quite a time to listener notice that something changed.

Comment: I've been trying to implement listeners for both files and folders with no luck. No error messages, everything exactly like in the DEMO, but the callbacks are never hit. Any ideas? Is it working in your environment? What changes cause reactions?

Comment: For me it was working, but with delay. It has been trigered by file update from other device.

Comment: How long was the delay until the onChange was fired? On the local device I get the onChange right away (not helpful). On the remote device, I've waited 10 mins and still nothing.